# How to get query parameters from URL?

Tags: ios, swift, url, firebase-dynamic-links

I am creating a manual Firebase Dynamic Link

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

I have a url in the format of https://test.page.link/?link=https://test.page.link/register?accessCode%3DAA000000&apn=com.test.foo&ibi=com.test.bar&ofl=https://www.google.com.

How can I get the value of accessCode?

```
extension URL {
    
    func valueOf(_ queryParameterName: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }

        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == queryParameterName })?.value
    }
}
```

Using this extension the query items are `link`, `apn`, and `ofl`.

`url.valueOf("link")` returns:

`https://test.page.link/?link=https://test.page.link/register?accessCode=AA000000`

I only need the `AA000000` returned.

Comment: There is "subURL", ie url inside url. You need to call that method on the `aQuery.value` to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Since `link` is of the format of a url, create a `URL` instance from it and then get the `accessCode` value using `valueOf(_:)` method like so,

```
if let link = url.valueOf("link"), let linkUrl = URL(string: link) {
    let accessCode = linkUrl.valueOf("accessCode")
    print(accessCode)
}
```

Comment: Great. Do accept if the answer helped. Happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

You have an URL inside an URL, more precisely, an URL inside a value of a query, so what about using:

```
extension URL {
    
    func valueOf(_ queryParameterName: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) else { return nil }
        guard let queryItems = url.queryItems else { return nil }
        for aQueryItem in queryItems {
            if aQueryItem.name == queryParameterName {
                return aQueryItem.value
            } else if let subvalue = aQueryItem.value, let subURL = URL(string: subvalue), let found = subURL.valueOf(queryParameterName) {
                return found
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can use `url.valueOf("accessCode")`

Comment: Had to make a little edit but now it can be used for all available parameter options

```
else if let subvalue = aQueryItem.value, let subURL = URL(string: subvalue) {
                if let subUrlValue = subURL.valueOf(queryParameterName) {
                    return subUrlValue
                }
            }
```

Comment: Oops, indeed, if it's not found on the subquery, forgot about that case. Good catch. Should be fixed.